# Problema com html na versão mobile

Tags: html

Então pessoal o negócio é o seguinte, eu acabei de editar o arquivo index.html do meu site e ta de boa quando visto pelo computador, porem se eu abro o site em um celular, as edições que fiz não aparece, ao invés disso aparece o layout antigo, eu já limpei caches cookies etc, abri em outro navegador mobile e nada, mas pelo navegador no pc ele aparece as modificações, o que será que pode ser?
obrigado

Comment: O celular já havia aberto o site anteriormente, podendo ter mantido-o em cache?

Comment: Tem link do site? Vc tinha arquivos .css diferentes pra versão mobile e desktop?

Answer (score 0):

Ola galera tudo bem? Então eu consegui resolver, eu abri o site e cliquei em inspecionar elemento e achei onde era o problema, era em uma barra  de opção que estava dando conflito com outra parte java script responsivo, então achei o código problemático no próprio índex.HTML bem embaixo onde tinha o código do HTML em versão mobile, então editei o código nesta parte mobile e funcionou, agora ta dr boa, mas agradeço a ajuda amigos fiquem com DEUS.